# Wavy cuts when cutting closet doors

Tags: doors, carpentry, closet, circular-saw

I have had this happen to me on a few closet doors I am installing. I needed to trim just a quarter inch off and I properly measure and set a straight edge before cutting. When cutting I am perfectly aligned with my measurements the entire way, but once I stand up the door the top is very wavy. So far this isn't an issue because I have trim hiding the tops, but on the next door you will be able to see the top. So I want to figure this out.

I haven't ever had issues cutting straight lines in plywood, it just seems with doors. Could it be a bent blade? I checked and it seems like my blade is square to the saw and I don't think it is a dull blade. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Try clamping a straight board across the door and using that to guide the saw. Or use of the aluminum cutting guides. http://www.homedepot.com/p/Johnson-98-in-Aluminum-Cutting-Guide-J4900/100188970?cm_mmc=Shopping%7cTHD%7cG%7c0%7cG-BASE-PLA-D25T-HandTools%7c&gclid=CjwKEAiAs_PCBRD5nIun9cyu01kSJAA-WD-r7ifxylsXATvLQLZr5k8-xUuh0MlnQMv1C1ipD8bwGRoCg1_w_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: What kind of saw did you use? circular saw or straight blade saw?

Comment: I did clamp a metal level as my guide. I am using a circular saw.

Answer (score 1):

How are you setting the circular saw when cutting? If you are clamping your straightedge so only the narrow part of the saw baseplate (1-1/2" or so away form the cut line) is on the wood, the saw is prone to wobble much moreso than when the wide part of the saw base is referenced (4-5" away from the cut.)

The other likely cause is that the surface profile of the face of the door (the raised panel section) is affecting the position of the blade as the baseplate rides along it - solve THAT by using a sawing straightedge that supports the saw above/on top of the door surface - something like a 1/2" piece of plywood 5-6 inches wide, with a straight board (or metal angle) screwed to the edge, using the saw to trim the edge of that plywood when the baseplate is run along the straightedge, and then you clamp the whole thing to the door with the cut edge aligned on your desired cut.

Something like this link, which I did not steal the idea from (it's  common idea) but which illustrates it *tolerably* well (they use an absurdly wide straightedge, I think) and I don't feel like taking the time to make my own illustrations, nor do I wish to steal theirs. http://www.woodworkersjournal.com/making-straight-cuts-with-a-circular-saw/

Then again, an even wider base might be easier to clamp down without getting in the way of the saw - several of their pictures seem like they have it clamped in such a way that they could not have started or won't be able to end the cut without running into the clamps.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a dull saw blade do that with a cut, also had a saw that the base was not aligned with the blade do that as well.

When either of these 2 conditions exist the saw will be very difficult to push through the wood, especially if you are using a straight edge/saw guide.